# How to get mic sensitivity slider to show in volume menu?

Tags: gui, 16.04, microphone

I have seen images where both the speaker volume and mic sensitivity have sliders for adjusting them in the drop-down menu from the speaker.

However after upgrading form Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 I don't seem to have a mic option.

How can I enable the mic slider to show?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mic is properly plugged in. My understanding is that the slider will automatically appear once a mic is plugged in.

Comment: It's a laptop so I guess it's always plugged in